# How to turn off LibreOffice API SDK Reference Browser?

Tags: libreoffice

I am using LibreOffice.  I managed to turn the API SDK Reference browser on by mistake.

How do I turn it off?  As it is, it is SSERIOUSLY getting in my way.

Comment: Try *Tools > Development Tools*.

Answer (score 1):

I found something.

Unlock the toolbar.